# Computing the limit $\lim_{k\to0}\frac{1}{2k^3}\int_0^k\frac{1-\cos 4x}{x^2+2}~\mathrm{d}x.$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

I want to compute the limit

$$\lim_{k\to0}\frac{1}{2k^3}\int_0^k\frac{1-\cos 4x}{x^2+2}~\mathrm{d}x.$$

I thought of using L'Hôpital, so I treated $2k^3$ as the denominator and the integral as the numerator and applied Leibniz to the numerator, and by applying limits I got $\frac{2}{3}$ as a result, but the answer is $0$?

Comment: but what about the limit, no l'hopital?

Comment: yes with l'hopital...

Comment: how is 0 reached as a result?

Comment: Use the substitution $t=x^3$ and apply fundamental theorem of calculus

Answer (score 2):

Since $$\cos(4x)=1-8x^2+x^2\varepsilon (x),$$
for some function $\varepsilon :\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $\varepsilon (x)\to 0$ whenever $x\to 0$, you get that

\begin{align*}
\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{1}{2k^3}\int_0^k\frac{1-\cos(4x)}{x^2+2}\,\mathrm d x&\underset{\text{Hospital}}{=}\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(4k)}{6k^2(k^2+2)}\\
&=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{8+\varepsilon (k)}{6(k^2+2)}\\
&=\frac{2}{3}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

We want to compute the limit

$$L=\lim_{k\to0}\frac{1}{2k^3}\int_0^k\frac{1-\cos 4x}{x^2+2}~\mathrm{d}x.$$

As you pointed out yourself, L'Hôpital's rule is a great idea, as we have an indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$. Using L'Hôpital's rule and the FTC we get that

$$L=\lim_{k\to0}\frac{1-\cos 4k}{6k^2(k^2+2)}=\lim_{k\to0}\frac{1-\cos 4k}{6k^4+12k^2}.$$

We're now in a $\frac{0}{0}$-situation again, and so we can one again apply L'Hôpital's rule to get that

$$L=\lim_{k\to0}\frac{4\sin4k}{24k^3+24k}=\lim_{k\to0}\frac{\sin4x}{6k^3+6k}.$$

Once again we have a $\frac{0}{0}$ indeterminate form, and so a final application of L'Hôpital's rule yields that

$$L=\lim_{k\to0}\frac{4\cos4k}{18k^2+6}=\frac{4}{6}=\frac{2}{3}.$$

Thus your answer that it equals $\frac{2}{3}$ is correct, and the "answer" saying it's zero is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$1-\cos 4x=2\sin^2 2x=8x^2(1+A(x))$ where $\lim_{x\to 0}A(x)=0.$

$\frac {1}{2+x^2}=\frac {1}{2}(1+B(x))$ where $\lim_{x\to 0}B(x)=0.$

So $(1+A(x))(1+B(x))=1+C(x)$ with $\lim_{x\to 0}C(x)=0.$

Let $U(k)=\sup_{|x|\le |k|}|C(x)|.$ Then $\lim_{k\to 0}U(k)=0.$ We have $$\int_0^k\frac {1-\cos 4x}{2+x^2}dx=\int_0^k4x^2(1+C(x))dx=$$ $$=\int_0^k4x^2dx+\int_0^k4x^2C(x)dx$$ and we have $$\left|\int_0^kx^2C(x)dx\right|\le \left|\int_0^kx^2|C(x)|dx\right|\le \left|\int_0^kx^2U(k)dx\right|=|k|^3U(k)/3.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
 & \quad \lim _{k \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2 k^{3}} \int_{0}^{k} \frac{1-\cos 4 x}{x^{2}+2} d x \quad\left(\frac{0}{0}\right)\\&=\lim _{k \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{1-\cos 4 k}{k^{2}+2}}{6 k^{2}}\\
&=\lim _{k \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin ^{2} 2 k}{3 k^{2}} \cdot \lim _{k \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{k^{2}+2}\\
&=\frac{2}{3} \lim _{k \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\sin 2 k}{2 k}\right)^{2}\\
&=\frac{2}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$